# Creating a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to execute a command CSRUN.exe with certain parameters from command prompt. I am able to do this using command prompt. Everytime instead of invoking this from the command prompt, i thought of writing a batch file, where in a single click will help me and also i forward this to someone who wants to execute.

Following is the one i am executing from the command prompt, which i want to have in a batch file

C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.1\bin>**csrun.exe E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.csx E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /launchbrowser**

Can somebody suggest me how to create a batch file for invoking this command?

Answer (score 1):

Just put those commands in a file

```
csrun.exe E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.csx E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /launchbrowser
```

and name it `something.bat`

Comment: I'm giving you all +1 for answering at the same exact time!

Answer (score 1):

Just copy

> csrun.exe E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.csx E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /launchbrowser

inside an empty file and save it as a `.bat`..

Comment: I'm giving you all +1 for answering at the same exact time!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [start](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm) command and, if csrun.exe is not in your path you will need to specify an exact path for it:

```
start csrun.exe E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.csx E:\Publish\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /launchbrowser
```

Save the above in a `.bat` file.

Also remember to put double quotes around paths with spaces in them.

Comment: @user113476: I'm giving you all +1 for answering at the same exact time!